# Django rest framework - exclude endpoint from authentication

Tags: django-rest-framework

I need to make view accessible without authentication, based on a variable passed in **urls.py**.

My idea is something like this:

**urls.py**

```
    url(r'^oidc-api/', include('api.urls'), {'logged': True})
```

**views.py**

```
    class ExampleViewSet(ModelViewSet):

      if logged: # How can I get this variable, passed in urls.py?
        permission_classes = () # This will exclude current view from authentication

      queryset = Widget.objects.filter(visible=True)
      serializer_class = ExampleSerializer
      filter_backends = (DjangoFilterBackend,)
      filter_fields = ('example_id',)
```

However, I can not access *logged* variable that is passed from **urls.py**.

John

Answer (score 2):

You can't do that.
What you could do is, remove those permission classes from the views ***manually*** or set those to an empty set as,

```
class ExampleViewSet(ModelViewSet):
    permission_classes = ()
```